# How to delete all the jobs from the printer

Tags: printing, c++builder

I am new to the C++ program. How to send the job to the printer and how to delete the jobs from the printer which is yet to be printed using win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

Open a handle to a printer using the [`OpenPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162751%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API call. Alternatively you might get this handle from the [Printers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Printers) unit in the VCL instead. When you have the handle you can use the [`SetPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145082%28VS.85%29.aspx) API call to reset (purge) the printer queue. Simply pass the `PRINTER_CONTROL_PURGE` as the command parameter.

I found a simple example using [VB (here)](http://www.berezniker.com/content/pages/visual-foxpro/how-delete-all-print-jobs-print-queue), which shows the use of the commands, if I find the time can make a somewhat similar example using C++.